Migrating MacOS to external SSD - slow startup
History:
I have Intel iMac 5K 2017 (iMac18,3). It has 1 TB Fusion Drive inside. I never reinstalled macOS since I bought it, just upgraded Sierra -> Mojave -> Ventura. Ventura is much slower on Fusion Drive, so I decided to buy a 2 TB external SSD with USB 3.1 type C interface.
It is a pain to reinstall everything, so I proceeded to clone. I logged in Internet Recovery (Option-Command-R), started the Disk Utility, created GUID Partition Table (GPT) and a 1 TB APFS container. Next, I used Disc Utility to restore my Fusion Drive APFS volume to the external SSD volume.
Problem:
I can successfully boot to this migrated SSD volume, but it boots very slowly. After booting, it runs pretty fast, so it shouldn't be a SSD issue. I measured some timings:




FusionDrive
SSD




Boot (to logon screen)
1:10
9:17


Logon
1:20
0:17


Starting Eclipse
0:44
0:17


Starting DBeaver
0:23
0:09


Starting FireFox
0:29
0:08



Did anyone experienced something similar? How would you solve this? Maybe there is known method for fixing this? I found advice to disconnect all drives, but I cannot disconnect the internal SDD and HDD. I have a couple ideas to try, but I don't know which one is better.

I could restore from Time Machine backup instead of cloning, but I feel it will be the same as cloning.
I could fresh install new MacOS, and then use migration assistant. Will it migrate everything?

Edit:
SSD model is 2 Tb Samsung 980 Pro NVME inside USB 3.1 Gen 2 external box. Max speed is 10 Gbps (I measured it). I'm fine with it, except boot time.
Edit2:
My journey continues. After fresh install boot time was 0:49, but eventually it returned to 4-6 minutes. Looking at log, I see these lines:
2024-07-14 13:16:03.308610+0700 0x243      Default     0x0                  1      0    launchd: [dirs_cleaner:] Doing boot task
2024-07-14 13:18:13.124240+0700 0x258      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) tx_leave:2401: disk5 tx xid 6920 took 106681145 us to close
2024-07-14 13:18:24.555732+0700 0x34e      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) tx_flush:803: disk5 tx xid 6921 was closed for 11412983 us waiting to prepare to flush
2024-07-14 13:18:24.556199+0700 0x258      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) tx_enter_internal:2279: disk5 waited 11413078 us to open tx xid 6922 (nx_tx_wait_closed)

I also found this article "macOS Monterey takes 25+ minutes to boot", so probably I'm not the only one. Meanwhile I will try to live with this, and to save money for better Thunderbolt 3 SSD enclosure box. If things get worse, I always could return back to internal fusion drive.

USB 3.1 Gen 1 (5 Gb/s) or USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10 Gb/s)? Might be better to just post the make and model of the USB SSD.

If you do a fresh install, then you could measure the boot timing before and after migrating. If a fresh install (before migrating) is slow, then you could try a Thunderbolt drive. A Thunderbolt drive is basically the same as the internal SDD, except the drive is outside of the Mac and is usually slightly slower than the internal SSD that came with your Mac.

I added SSD model to the bottom. Thunderbolt drive is too expensive for me. I'll try fresh install today.

About the cheapest reasonably fast Thunderbolt 3 enclosure I could find would be the OWC Envoy Pro SX. The OWC Envoy Express is cheaper, but not at fast.


Did you make sure to explicitly select the external drive in the Startup Disk system setting, rather than leaving it unselected? Leaving it unselected will cause time to be spent scanning the system bus for a valid boot drive. 2. Boot in Verbose Mode (hold Command + V during boot) and let us know the time it takes from boot chime to first boot message, then see if there is a stall around any boot message (take a photo if so). 3. Try booting to single-user mode (Command + S during boot) and see if that changes timing.


It seems this problem was accidentally solved. The root cause was Karabiner kernel extension for their virtual keyboard driver. Somehow it didn't survive cloning internal HDD to external SSD. I deinstalled it and reinstalled again. Since then system boots without issues.
